# How do i bypass the random id in array that firebase gives on response?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this is my console.log but i can only access the name not the messages,
im able to print the name but when i try to print the messages i get [object][object] on the page when i print the data, want to remove the -LCE-36m4sdrPGFpusM6:

//output

```
messages:
 -LCE-36m4sdrPGFpusM6:
 date:"2018/5/11"
 haveConsultant:true
 hour:"12:40"
 message:"hi"
name:"Teste chat 2"
```

My code to print this output with angular coming from firebase , how can i do to access the message nested array???

```
getUsersChat() {

    let clientsKeys: Array < any > ;

    let i = 0;
    console.log('obter chats ativados');
    this.mySegService.getChats().take(1).subscribe(res => {

      clientsKeys = Object.keys(res);
      this.totalNumberClients += clientsKeys.length;
      clientsKeys.forEach(clientKey => {
        if (i < ++i && res[clientKey]['messages'] !== undefined) {
          this.clientsShortList.push({
            name: res[clientKey]['name'],
            messages: res[clientKey]['messages']
          });
        }
        i += 1;
      });

    console.log(this.clientsShortList);
   });

  }
```

// my html code

```
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let chat of clientsShortList">
    <mat-icon mat-list-icon>account_circle</mat-icon>
    <h4 mat-line>{{chat.name}}</h4>
    <button mat-button>see more</button>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first get the random id using `Object.keys` like this:

```
var key = Object.keys(res[clientKey]['messages'])[0];
```

And then get the message object like this:

```
console.log(res[clientKey]['messages'][key])
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible simple solution to this problem would be to `JSON.stringify` the messages object before attempting to `console.log` it.

Depending on the browser and format of the object, just calling `console.log(obj)` won't always do the trick.

In your case this would be a change to the line:

```
messages: res[clientKey]['messages']
```

to instead be

```
messages: JSON.stringify(res[clientKey]['messages'])
```